# counter gets reset java

Tags: java, counter, increment, operator-keyword

I am working on a school assignment.

The assignment was to make a program that will randomly choose a number and the user has to guess that certain number.

the program should keep count(count var) of the amount of times that the user submitted an input.

I know that the problem that the counter is being reset comes from the initialization  step of the method.... is there a way  to bypass the initialization  step if the value of my count variable is higher than 0?

I have submitted my code below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomnumber = rand.nextInt(50);

        int machine = GuessMachine(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("gok een getal")), randomnumber);

    }

    public static int CallPane(int Value, int rndNumber) {
        int X1;
        X1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("gok een getal3"));
        int machine = GuessMachine(X1, rndNumber);
        return X1;
    }


    public static int GuessMachine(int InputNumber, int rndNumber) {
        int value = InputNumber;
        int randomNumber = rndNumber;
        int count=0;


        if (InputNumber == randomNumber) {
            count =+1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goed! Je deed er "+count+" keer " );

            int Response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Nog een keer spelen?", "Bevestigen",

                   JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            if (Response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "tot de volgende keer");
            } 
            else if (Response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int randomnumber = rand.nextInt(50);
                //callpane
                int machine = GuessMachine(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("gok een getal")), randomnumber);

            }

        }
        else if (InputNumber < randomNumber) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "te weinig");

            int PaneInput = CallPane(value, randomNumber);
            count+=1;
        } 
       else if (InputNumber > randomNumber) {
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"teveel", "information", >INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "teveel");
        int PaneInput = CallPane(value, randomNumber);
         count=+1;
      }



      return value;

   }
```

----updated the code after suggestion---

```
   public static int count=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomnumber = rand.nextInt(50);

        int machine = GuessMachine(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("gok een getal")), randomnumber);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, count);
    }

    public static int CallPane(int Value, int rndNumber) {
        int X1;
        X1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("gok een getal3"));
        int machine = GuessMachine(X1, rndNumber);
        return X1;
    }


    public static int GuessMachine(int InputNumber, int rndNumber) {
        int value = InputNumber;
        int randomNumber = rndNumber;



        if (InputNumber == randomNumber) {
            count +=1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goed! Je deed er "+count+" keer " );

            int Response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Nog een keer spelen?", "Bevestigen",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            if (Response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "tot de volgende keer");
            } 
            else if (Response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int randomnumber = rand.nextInt(50);
                //callpane
                int machine = GuessMachine(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("gok een getal")), randomnumber);

            }

        }
        else if (InputNumber < randomNumber) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "te weinig");

            int PaneInput = CallPane(value, randomNumber);
            count+=1;
        } 
        else if (InputNumber > randomNumber) {
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"teveel", "information", INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "teveel");

            int PaneInput = CallPane(value, randomNumber);
            count+=1;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your program,everywhere you have used count=+1; Correct it and then execute again, modify as count+=1;

Comment: @404Student shekhar has found your problem. You should accept his answer.

Comment: @Spundun No, it didn't solve the problem...

Comment: @404Student Please update the code here, because your current code is obviously wrong. Please paste the new fixed code that you tried and is still not working.

Comment: @404Student I think when you had replied, your updated code was not yet visible. I see the updated code now. There is one more bug that you are incrementing your count way too late. I've updated my answer to explain that. Try that also and let me know if it works now.

Comment: @Spundun Yes! your last suggestion definitely did the trick... first I moved my count var right after the if statement, that did the trick... afterwards I moved the count var to  the top of my guessmachine method to remove count from the if statements...
your 4point suggestion definitely did the trick..Many Thanks to you and all the others for your time and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Like shekhar said you need to update the code to be `count +=1` or to be safe `count = count + 1`
2. Like CDahn said, the variable `count` needs to be static, because it has to preserve value across calls to the functions
3. Every time `GuessMachine` is called the count will get reset. Think about how `GuessMachine` will be getting called again and again. This means you will be executing `count = 0` at the top of the function `GuessMachine` again and again. You need to take the initialization of `count = 0` out of the function `GuessMachine` and into the function `main` because even after you make it static, if you initialize it every time you call GuessMachine, the `count` will keep getting reset.
4. There is another issue with your code. In the `if` block in `GuessMachine` 2 out of 3 times, the `count` is incremented way too late. It needs to be incremented immediately. In fact it is the same exact piece of code so we can take it out of the `if` block

   ```
   public static int GuessMachine(int InputNumber, int rndNumber) {
       int value = InputNumber;
       int randomNumber = rndNumber;
       count = count + 1;
       if (InputNumber == randomNumber) {
           // count +=1; No need for this statement anymore because we moved it out.
           ...
   ```

I suggest you stepping through the program. Try "dry running" and also try using a debugger to step through each statement, and get a feel for the control flow of this code. Seems like you need a lot of practice understanding how to design code and debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Make the count variable a class member:

```
public:
    static int count;
```

Then in GuessMachine you remove the local variable by the same name.

Comment: You need to apply both @CDahn and shekhar's solutions together.

Comment: It's not `C++`, colon shouldn't be used.

Comment: @spundun I did, but when the user guesses the correct number lets say the random number is 10 and the user puts in number 10 in 3 turns the message pane returns 1 instead of a 3:  if (InputNumber == randomNumber) {
        count +=1;//error 1
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goed! Je deed er "+count+" keer " );.
But if I call the count var in my main it shows the real amount of times that the user had to guess.. can you explain why?

Comment: @404Student You still haven't posted the new code. Make a new section in your question titled update, and post the latest code you tried over there.

Answer (score 1):

1. What you have done in your entire code is you have mis-typed as **count=+1;** Also, the count variable must be declared as a class attribute as **public static int count=0;**
2. Also, you are incrementing count after calling the CallPane() method, because of which it is never able to get incremented!

This is the error,and hence being reset every-time! Replace this statement everywhere with **count+=1;** Moreover, also declare `count as static` to be updated by incrementing from anywhere within the class. It'll work fine! I have shown it below :-

```
public class JavaApplication5 {

public static int count=0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
Random rand = new Random();
int randomnumber = rand.nextInt(50);
System.out.println("The random number is "+randomnumber);
int machine = GuessMachine(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number :- ")), randomnumber);
}

public static int CallPane(int Value, int rndNumber) {
int X1;
X1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number :- "));
int machine = GuessMachine(X1, rndNumber);
return X1;
}

public static int GuessMachine(int InputNumber, int rndNumber) {
int value = InputNumber;
int randomNumber = rndNumber;
if(InputNumber == randomNumber) {
    count +=1;//error 1
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Well! You did it "+count+" times." );
    int Response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Play again", "Confirm",
           JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if (Response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "See you later!");
    } 
    else if (Response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomnumber = rand.nextInt(50);
        //callpane
        int machine = GuessMachine(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number :- ")), randomnumber);
    }
}
    else if (InputNumber < randomNumber) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient!");
    count+=1;//error 2
    int PaneInput = CallPane(value, randomNumber);
} 
    else if (InputNumber > randomNumber) {
    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"teveel", "information", >INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Excess!");
   count+=1;//error 3
   int PaneInput = CallPane(value, randomNumber);
   }
  return value;
 }

}
```

Comment: tried this to, but it didn't work( suppose my random number was 45 and it took me  4 turns to guess that number, the program tells me that I guessed it correctly in the first try...)

Comment: Now I have amended it in English language and executed myself, check it.

Answer (score 0):

A way of initializing count variable is shown below: I did one count variable  and two method initializeCount() and incrementalCount(). Every time I get a count variable I update it by adding 1 by method incrementalCount(). When I need initialize the variable again I use initializeCount();

```
public class YourClass {

private static int count = 0;

public static void initializeCount(){
    this.count = 0;
}

public static int incrementalCount(){
   this.count++;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

Random rand = new Random();
int randomnumber = rand.nextInt(50);

initializeCount(); // for initializing the count variable    

int machine = GuessMachine(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("gok een getal")), randomnumber);

}

...

//Then you can use.
public static int GuessMachine(int InputNumber, int rndNumber) {
    int value = InputNumber;
    int randomNumber = rndNumber;
    // int count=0;

    if (InputNumber == randomNumber) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goed! Je deed er "+incrementalCount()+" keer " );

        .... 

        else if (Response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int randomnumber = rand.nextInt(50);

                initializeCount(); // for initializing the count variable    

                //callpane
                int machine = GuessMachine(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("gok een getal")), randomnumber);

            }

        ...
    }    
}

...

}
```